# Microsoft Windows Notification Service IP address range

Tags: windows

I've a problem with windows notification service, I am going to send notifications from behind a firewall system and I would like to know the possible IPs (IP range) that need to be allowed in the firewall for the notification service

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows PUSH Notification Service? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx

Comment: Yes, Windows PUSH Notification Service

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends that you use DNS based firewall rules. You need to have the following destination open for port 443:

```
https://next-services.apps.microsoft.com
https://*.wns.windows.com      
https://*.notify.windows.com  
https://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com
```

If you cannot do that, you need to use the IP list Microsoft provides and update it about every 2- 3 weeks:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44238

Answer (score 0):

No specific ports needs to be open in your server configuration. MPNS uses regular http or https requests.